# Write SQL to verify cumulative sum

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table structure

| accountID | amount | total | seq |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | 1 | 10 | 0 |
| a1 | -10 | 11 | 1 |
| a1 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| a2 | 20 | 1 | 0 |
| *a2* | *1* | *1* | *1* |

The `total` of the first record is not necessary to be 0

If its not the first record, the current `total` should be calculated by `previous_record.amount + previous_record.total`

In the example above,
I want to select the last record because the `total` is wrong. It supposes equal to 21 (1+20).

I have coded a program that retrieve all data and do the verification.
But the data size is too big (~1M records). It takes really long time. So I seek a solution that use SQL.

Comment: Your question is ambiguous.  Do you want the rows where the total is off?  Do you want the rows where the calculated totals are off?  For instance, if there were a fourth row for the first account, with the values of 3/3 would you want it included?  If the values were 3/1 would you want it?  (The first is correct based on the data in the previous row; the second is correct based on the data in all previous rows.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may flag any offending record using the `LAG()` function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, LAG(total) OVER (PARTITION BY accountID ORDER BY seq) AS lag_total,
              LAG(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY accountID ORDER BY seq) AS lag_amount
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT accountID, amount, total, seq
FROM cte
WHERE total <> lag_amount + lag_total;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo